# drupal_get_private_key equivalent Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drupal

I'm trying to convert the theme from Drupal to Wordpress, I don't know a lot about drupal, so this function "drupal_get_private_key" confuses me a little and I can't really find a lot of documentation about it. Could someone explain me what is this function about and how could I do this in Wordpress?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Drupal uses this to generate the paths to files* (its used in other stuff too, but in themming I believe its the main reason).

*These files are the files created by users, not the files in the theme folder. The folders are configured in the admin and, when an user uploads a **news picture**, for example, it will be placed in the configured folder.

You problably just want to find another way to find these paths.